# Getting Illegal Invocation executing 'query' on 'Permissions'

Tags: javascript, permissions, seo

I am getting an error from an SEO tool saying that I am making an Illegal Invocation executing 'query' on 'Permissions'

Here is the full error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'query' on 'Permissions': Illegal invocation at Permissions.window.navigator.permissions.__proto__.query (<anonymous>:11:19)
```

And here is the code in question - Note, I am NOT receiving this error on the web page, or when stepping through the code, I'm just trying to determine what the SEO tool is trying to tell me, and how to resolve it.

```
try {
      if(!!navigator.permissions && !!navigator.permissions.query){
        navigator.permissions.query({name: 'geolocation'}).then(function (permission) {
          !!permission && permission.state === 'granted'
            ? navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
              //Do Stuff here:
              resolve(request);
            },
            function () {//current position error.
              resolve(request)
            })
            //otherwise, just return the original request.
            : resolve(request);
        })
      } else { resolve(request)}
    } catch (ex) {//permissions query error
      resolve(request);
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the SEO tool. Since you haven't specified which tool it is, it's going to be hard to research.

Comment: The tool is seositecheckup.com

Comment: This could be a false positive by their Javascript parser.